# jpegtran jpeg with -scale 8/16 can't be opened, smartscaling issue?

Tags: c, libjpeg, dct, libjpeg-turbo, jpegtran

I m trying get a scaled down version of a jpeg with jpegtran by using the scaling feature.

this works (it produces a jpeg that can be opened by any program)

```
cjpeg.exe -scale 8/16 -outfile halfrez.jpg -optimize -progressive fullrez.ppm
```

but this don't (it produces a jpeg that can't be opened by windows explorer or chrome for example)

```
jpegtran.exe -scale 8/16 -outfile halfrez.jpg -optimize -progressive fullrez.jpg
```

I suspect that jpegtran is using the new smartscaling feature that makes the jpeg not compatible, but with block size of 8 it should be ok and it's working with the cjpeg compressor.

any help on how I scale the jpeg with DCT and stile being compatible?

Comment: How is this related to C language?

Comment: @Gerhardh both tools have a C API if a c api solution exist I would like to use it

Comment: "Doesn't work" is no error description. In which way does it fail? Does the program throw an error message? Is the resulting file not usable in a certain program?

Comment: If you want to use a C API, then please show us your sorce code that you have written so far. Using a 3rd party program is a total different thing. Those would be different questions.

Comment: yes I wrote it in the title "it can't be opened" I will modify the text